# Running function on EDT from doInBackground

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I want to run a certain function from doInBackground on the EDT. I have it currently setup using publish and process which is working just fine. However, I want to know if there is a way to have a function run on the EDT from doInBackground without using publish and process. Also, without using invokeLater. Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this as you would queue any code onto the EDT: via a Runnable that is added to the event queue:

```
   protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {

      // code to be called off of the EDT

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

            // code to be called on the EDT

         }
      });
      return null;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, should have specified no invokeLater or publish and process.

Comment: @Graham: what do you mean "no invokeLater" as that makes no sense. Why could you not use invokeLater as that ***is*** the solution and there is no other?

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to know. If there is another solution other than invokeLater or publish and process. If there's not then my question is answered.